# Массивы в PostgreSQL - какие есть юзкейсы?

Tags: массивы, postgresql

Читаю мануал по PostgreSQL. Раздел [Конструктор массивов](http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) сильно меня озадачил. Не могу себе представить, где можно использовать создание массивов на стороне СУБД. Если не трудно, смоделируйте ситуацию, когда эта фича сильно удобна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массивы могут понадобиться, например, для того, чтобы фильтровать/сортировать какие-либо данные.

К примеру, на работе я столкнулся с такой ситуацией, когда у нас однородные данные в таблице вводятся в несколько полей, например, Город1, Город2, Город3, Город4, а потом, в дальнейшем, необходимо эти 4 значения выбрать и отсортировать. Да, это неграмотно спроектированная часть БД, но как показывает практика, такие случаи сплошь и рядом:[

Вообще, я считаю, что это очень крутая штука, и когда я реализовывал хранимые процедуры в БД MSSQL, этого очень не хватало, вместо этого приходилось заморачиваться с созданием временных таблиц.